# Mnesia bad_object_header error

Tags: database, erlang, mnesia

I am getting an unusual error with some simple mnesia code. This question is a followup to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031683/random-bad-object-header-mnesia-error) of mine, but now I have code to reproduce the issue.

I am using this erlang:

> Erlang R16B01 (erts-5.10.2) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

on Arch Linux.

If I have this code:

```
-module(test).

-export([test/0, tryread/0]).

-record(rec, { a, b }).

test() ->
    install(),

    {atomic, ok} = mnesia:transaction(fun() -> mnesia:write({rec, y, y}) end),
    {atomic, ok} = mnesia:transaction(fun() -> mnesia:write({rec, z, z}) end).

tryread() ->
    mnesia:transaction(fun() ->
                               mnesia:read(rec, y)
                       end).

install() ->
    mnesia:create_schema([node()]),

    ok = mnesia:start(),

    {atomic, ok} = mnesia:create_table(rec, [
                                             {attributes,       record_info(fields, rec)},
                                             {disc_only_copies, [node()]},
                                             {type,             set}
                                            ]).
```

in a file called `test.erl` and I start `erl` and type the following in:

```
1> c(test).
{ok,test}
2> test:test().
{atomic,ok}
3> test:tryread().
{atomic,{error,{bad_object_header,"/.../Mnesia.nonode@nohost/rec.DAT"}}}
```

As a side note, if I exit `erl` and restart it, and do `mnesia:start()`, I get this warning:

> dets: file "/.../Mnesia.nonode@nohost/rec.DAT" not properly closed, repairing ...

This is very reliable behaviour for me. I can delete the entire database, rerun the test, and get the exact same results.

One thing is that if I put the call to `tryread` inside the `test` function right after the two transactions, it works fine. It is calling `tryread` from the REPL that causes the error.

If I downgrade my erlang Arch installation package to R16B-3 from R16B01-1, I do not get this error. Any version newer than that gives this error.

Can anyone else reproduce this error? What is causing it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on R15B in windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this on R16B01 on my machine.

Some things to look out for:

- You must call mnesia:stop() properly when closing down mnesia. If you hard-exit the shell, your DETS tables on disk will need repair, which is probably what you are experiencing.
- Is there any particular reason you want DETS copies through `disc_only_copies` ? Event `disc_copies` is way faster since they keep the data set in memory as well as on a disk log on the disk. For purely disk-based storage, there are other options which usually fares better than mnesia in my experience.
- My guess is that you end up with a wrong misconfigured scheme for some reason. A guess could be something with permissions. rec.DAT could be corrupted, but I don't know what is making it tilt in that direction.

Comment: I am not stopping the shell or mnesia between creating the database and using it, so bullet point one cannot be the problem. Furthermore, the "repairing file" message is only a second symptom, the more important one is the `bad_object_header` error when trying to do `mnesia:read`. Thank you for the recommendation about `disc_only_copies`. All the required permissions are available to the shell so bullet point three can't be the problem either.

Comment: My guess is somewhat close. The error comes from `dets_utils` lines 154 and 169. We are trying to execute a `file:pread` scatter/gather read and we are getting either an `einval` or `enomem` error back.

Comment: Is there a way I can check which one it is?

Comment: No, not apart from recompiling the code or adding tracing to the file:pread call from within the correct `dets` process.